# ul li circle design with a text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

hello guys I'm new to programming and I can't seem to find any related search about what I am trying to do.

Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApKhB.jpg)

can someone please help me.

My code is like this in my li and ul

```
ul {
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        li {
          float: right;
        }

        li a {
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
          background-color: #111111;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do..?

Comment: the same as that image link @Lee

Comment: You want the first link to have a white outline..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially you are only needing to add a border, and then a border-radius in CSS to curve the edges.

Here's a basic example, based on what you have:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  float:right; /* Float the main list element instead */
}

li {
  display:inline-block; /* Don't float your list items, float the list itself */
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin:0 10px; */ I've changed the padding and margin of the list items to help them display more like the image*/
}


/* You need a border and border-radius to curve it */
li:first-child {
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-radius:15px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/leecollingsco/sj2utx7c/

Comment: that was great . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want circle in all li elements on selection than use:

```
ul li {
  border:2px solid #fff;
  border-radius:15px;
}
```